# Sylius grid creation for doctrine mongo

Tags: php, grid, sylius, doctrine-mongodb

I want to create a grid to display mongo documents using doctrine/mongodb odm driver. but i am getting the error

**" The parameter "sylius.mongodb.odm.repository.class" must be defined.".**

To solve this issue i have added the repository as below.

```
sylius_resource:
    drivers:
        - doctrine/orm
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm
    resources:
        goldco.order_state_transition:
            driver: doctrine/mongodb-odm
            classes:
                model:  Goldco\Document\OrderStateTransitionLog
                repository: Goldco\Repository\PayvisionCCTokenRepository
```

But after this i am getting the error like below

**Argument 4 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must implement interface Sylius\Component\Resource\Repository\RepositoryInterface, instance of Goldco\Repository\PayvisionCCTokenRepository given, called in /var/www/html/qoneco/var/cache/crmqoneco/ContainerFxuAVPx/getGoldco_Controller_OrderStateTransitionService.php on line 25**

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks